# Getting Error In Flutter Project In Style XML file

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here][1]

In this I am getting error as shown in image. Though its not showing error on application launch, but I am bit worried that if this run into error in future or at user end. Can anyone please let me know is this is a serious problem and do i need to worry this error ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRQAP.png

Comment: make sure command line is closed

Comment: Hi, the command line is closed everything is perfect but despite of it this errors appears.